# JavaFX - How to make containers resizable by the user

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am starting to work on javafx and i am struggling on how to make a container (pane, anchorpane, etc..) resizable by the end user. In WPF, this is very easy to do. I can do the resizing manually by code but i was thinking there might be just a setting to enable resizing that i havent found yet.

I am not particularly just want to fit something on a window. I would like to just give the end user the ability to resize a pane for his own liking.

Comment: You can use a `SplitPane` for example.

Comment: Yeah so far it is the best solution as i would like to resize horizontally only. I am using the border pane. and i would want the left pane to resize with the center pane. However i guess i just need to use the split pane on the at the center. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SplitPane for example. – DVarga

This was the best answer so far.

I could use this and put it instead at the center of my border pane since i need to resize horizontally